# What is the probability that there are three or more consecutive numbers in these six cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

52 poker cards (except the red and black jokers), 6 cards are drawn from them. What is the probability that there are three or more consecutive numbers in these six cards?

I think the problem is so complex…

Comment: Yes, it's complicated. It's not a fair question if it's supposed to be computed exactly. An approximate answer can be had by simulation. Where is the questio from?

Comment: From our poker game

Comment: @quasi From our poker game

Comment: Using a computer program, a brute-force count yields an exact probability of
$$
\frac{131877}{363545}
$$
which evaluates to approximately $.36$.

Comment: @quasi Can you show your code? The result I calculated with mathematica is the same as yours, but the answer from this friend below is different from ours. I don't know what went wrong

Comment: My code is just a routine brute-force count, nothing much to look at, but the result is definitely correct.

Comment: @quasi thank you again ！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $\{A23, 234, \ldots, JQK\}$ are the favourable outcomes. Calculation is a little bit more involved but largely similar if you including $QKA$ and/or $KA2$

Define $E_i$ be the event that each of the card $i, i+1, i+2$ appear at least once in the $6$ card sample, for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, 11$. The required probability is

$$ \begin{align} P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{11} E_i\right) 
=&~ \sum_{i=1}^{11}P(E_i) 
- \sum_{i < j}^{10}P(E_i\cap E_j) 
+ \sum_{i < j < k}^{9}P(E_i\cap E_j \cap E_k) \\
&-  \sum_{i < j < k < l}^{8}P(E_i\cap E_j \cap E_k \cap E_l)
\end{align}$$

Here the inclusion-exclusion principle stop at four events as we can have at most $6$ consecutive numbers, each appearing exactly once, which will lead to $4$ events, e.g. $E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4$ happen at the same time $\{123, 234, 345, 456\}$

For the event $E_i$, consider the 4-tuple containing the number of cards appear for card $i, i+1, i+2$, and the group of cards with the remaining $10$ numbers. The favorable configurations are
$$ (1,1,1,3), (2,1,1,2), (2,2,1,1), (2,2,2,0), (3,1,1,1), (3,2,1,0), (4,1,1,0) $$

i.e. the first one $(1,1,1,3)$ meaning exactly $1$ card $i$, $1$ card $(i+1)$, $1$ card $(i+2)$, and $3$ cards from the remaining group.
These need to be multiply by the possible distinct permutations of the three numbers, in the above order,
$$ 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 6, 3 $$

E.g. the configuration $(1,1,1)$ has $1$ distinct permutation, but $(2,1,1)$ has $3$.

So using the multi-hypergeometric pmf, we have the probability of $(1,1,1,3)$
$$ \frac {\displaystyle \binom {4} {1} \binom {4} {1} \binom {4} {1} \binom {40} {3}}
{\displaystyle \binom {52} {6}} \times 1 $$
as we have $4$ cards in the deck for each of the number $i, i+1, i+2$, and a total of $4 \times 10 = 40$ cards for the remaining group. And multiply by the number of distinct permutation $1$.

Summing them together,

$$ \begin{align} P(E_i) =&~ \frac {\binom {4} {1} \binom {4} {1} \binom {4} {1} \binom {40} {3}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 1
+ \frac {\binom {4} {2} \binom {4} {1} \binom {4} {1} \binom {40} {2}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 3
+ \frac {\binom {4} {2} \binom {4} {2} \binom {4} {1} \binom {40} {1}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 3
+ \frac {\binom {4} {2} \binom {4} {2} \binom {4} {2} \binom {40} {0}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 1 \\
&+ \frac {\binom {4} {3} \binom {4} {1} \binom {4} {1} \binom {40} {1}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 3
+ \frac {\binom {4} {3} \binom {4} {2} \binom {4} {1} \binom {40} {0}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 6
+ \frac {\binom {4} {4} \binom {4} {1} \binom {4} {1} \binom {40} {0}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 3 \\
=&~ \frac {882760} {20358520} = \frac {22069} {508963} \end{align}$$

Alternatively, we can make use of the inclusion-exclusion principle to take advantage of the complementary event. Let $F_i$ be the event that the card $i$ appear at least once, such that $E_i = F_i \cap F_{i+1} \cap F_{i+2}$.

Then
$$ \begin{align} P(E_i) &= 1 - P(E_i^c) \\
&= 1 - P(F_i^c \cup F_{i+1}^c \cup F_{i+2}^c) \\
&= 1 - P(F_i^c) \times 3 + P(F_i^c \cap F_{i+1}^c) \times 3 - P(F_i^c \cap F_{i+1}^c \cap F_{i+2}^c) \\ 
&= 1 - \frac {\binom {4} {0} \binom {48} {6}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 3
+ \frac {\binom {4} {0} \binom {4} {0} \binom {44} {6}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 3 
- \frac {\binom {4} {0} \binom {4} {0} \binom {4} {0} \binom {40} {6}} {\binom {52} {6}} \\
&= 1 - \frac {19475760} {20358520} = \frac {882760} {20358520} 
\end{align} $$

And this is the same for all $11$ $P(E_i)$

Next, for $E_i \cap E_j$, $i < j$, we need to consider the case where $j = i+1$, $j = i+2$, and $j \geq i + 3$

For $j = i + 1$, we are consider the $4$ consecutive number case. So using similar argument,
$$ \begin{align} P(E_i \cap E_{i+1}) &= 1 - P(E_i^c \cup E_{i+1}^c) \\
&= 1 - P(F_i^c \cup F_{i+1}^c \cup F_{i+2}^c \cup F_{i+3}^c) \\
&= 1 - P(F_i^c) \times 4 + P(F_i^c \cap F_{i+1}^c) \times 6 - P(F_i^c \cap F_{i+1}^c \cap F_{i+2}^c) \times 4 \\
&+ P(F_i^c \cap F_{i+1}^c \cap F_{i+2}^c \cap F_{i+3}^c) \\
&=  1 - \frac {\binom {4} {0} \binom {48} {6}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 4
+ \frac {\binom {4} {0} \binom {4} {0} \binom {44} {6}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 6 
- \frac {\binom {4} {0} \binom {4} {0} \binom {4} {0} \binom {40} {6}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 4
+ \frac {\binom {4} {0} \binom {4} {0} \binom {4} {0} \binom {4} {0} \binom {36} {6}} {\binom {52} {6}} \\
& = 1 - \frac {20137464} {20358520} = \frac {221056} {20358520}\\
\end{align} $$

And it is the same for all $10$ cases of $P(E_i, E_{i+1})$

Similarly for $j = i+2$, we require $5$ consecutive numbers to appear at least once.

$$ \begin{align} P(E_i, E_{i+2}) &= 
1 - \frac {\binom {48} {6}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 5 
+ \frac {\binom {44} {6}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 10
- \frac {\binom {40} {6}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 10
+ \frac {\binom {36} {6}} {\binom {52} {6}} \times 5
- \frac {\binom {32} {6}} {\binom {52} {6}}\\
&= 1 - \frac {20318072} {20358520} = \frac {40448} {20358520}
\end{align} $$
and it is the same for all $9$ of them.

For $j \geq i+3$ case, we have $6$ distinct numbers each appearing exactly once. So
$$ P(E_i \cap E_j) = \frac {\binom {4} {1}^6} {\binom {52} {6}} 
= \frac {4096} {20358520} $$
and it is the same for all $\binom {11} {2} - 10 - 9 = 36$ cases

Next, for $E_i \cap E_j \cap E_k$, $i < j < k$, we have $5$ consecutive numbers appear exactly once when $j = i+1, k = i+2$, or $6$ consecutive numbers when $j = i+1, i+2$, and $k = i+3$. For the remaining cases the event is null as it require more than $6$ numbers to appear.

For $5$ consecutive numbers we have probability $\frac {40448} {20358520}$, with the number of cases being $9$.

For $6$ consecutive numbers we have $\frac {4096} {20358520}$, with the number of cases being $8 \times 2 = 16$

At last, for $E_i \cap E_j \cap E_k \cap E_k \cap E_l$, $i < j < k < l$,
it must be $6$ consecutive numbers appearing exactly once each, with probability $\frac {4096} {20358520}$ for all $8$ cases. For the remaining cases the event is null as it require more than $6$ numbers to appear.

As a result, Combining all together

$$ \begin{align} P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{11} E_i\right) 
=&~ \frac {882760} {20358520} \times 11 \\
&~ - \frac {221056} {20358520} \times 10 
- \frac {40448} {20358520} \times 9
- \frac {4096} {20358520} \times 36 \\
&~ + \frac {40448} {20358520} \times 9 + \frac {4096} {20358520} \times 16 \\
&~ - \frac {4096} {20358520} \times 8 \\
=&~ \frac {7385112} {20358520} = \frac {131877} {363545} \approx 0.362753
\end{align}$$

Tedious but still manageable.

Comment: Thank you a lot ！

Comment: Yesterday using a computer program Mathematica, we get  an exact probability of
$$
\frac{131877}{363545}
$$
which evaluates to approximately $.36$, but not the same as yours , so I don't know which  went wrong…

Comment: Yes I could have some calculation error as I have not really double checking that yet. The above fraction converts to $7385112 / 20358520$, so I will need to check the difference of $7393304 - 7385112 = 8192 = 4096 \times 2$. I over count the $3$-event, $6$ consecutive cases wrongly as that will be $8 \times 2$ instead of $9 \times 2$. I edit the answer later.

Comment: Thank you ! That's great !

Comment: I corrected and the answer match. I am not sure about the other mistake part yet.